# How do I change user ownership

Tags: permissions

I recently fat-fingered a permissions change in my `/home/randy` folder. When I check permissions by booting off a live session cd I see user is 1000. I can't gain access to it. Is all lost?

Hey Guys, I tried these. I wasn't able to boot into the grub menu. When I press and hold the left shift key during boot it just keeps booting normally. If I push it too early it brings up a "keyboard" error. I can get into the terminal per wayzhc and Pilot6 instructions. I run the command

```
sudo chown -R randy:randy /home/randy
```

It asks for my password. I give it. I accepts it. It runs it but then I have to shut down as when I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> it goes back to the screen I got after I clicked out of the message windows. When I boot normally it still gives the same error which is... right after I enter user name and password during normal boot I get these 3 messages... First

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/randy/.ICEauthority
```

Then I get

```
There is a problem with the configuration server. (/usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconfig-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256)
```

Last I get...

```
Nautilus could not create the following required folders:/home/randy/Desktop,/home/randy/.nuatilus. (before running Nautilus, please create these folders or set permissions such that Nautilus can create them.)
```

Remember I'm running 10.04 LTS I'm very inexperienced at Ubuntu even though I've run it for years. It's been problem free for me until I tried to change the permissions of a photo folder. That's when the problem started. I'm VERY inexperienced at using the terminal.

By the way... when I ran the line

```
getent passwd 1000
```

per muru's request it returned this.

```
randy:x:1000:1000:Randy Thibeau,,,:/home/randy:bin/bash
```

Whatever that all means!

Comment: Unless you added additional users, the first user (aka the user you created on installation) has ID 1000. What does `getent passwd 1000` say (from a normal boot)?

Comment: Add the output of `ls -al /home/randy/.ICEauthority` and `ls -lad /home/randy/`

Comment: Specifically how do I do this? I should have prefaced this by thanking all of you for your patience. As I said I've not used or learned much about using the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Once you booted normally to the login screen, hit `ctrl + alt + F1` to access terminal. Login there and use command

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<usergroup> /home/randy
```

For example

```
sudo chown -R randy:randy /home/randy
```

If you have set a custom group for yourself, you can see it with `groups <username>`. Your group is the first one after `:`.

`-R` makes sure all the subfolders and files inside the /home/randy will get the same permissions.

`ctrl + alt + F7` to get back to graphical and login normally.

If you can't boot to login screen, use A.B's guide for recovery mode.

Comment: In a Live System is no user randy, therefore the user can't be set.

Comment: Live session is not needed for this. He should still be able to boot and access terminal (ctrl + alt + F1). If not, he should be able to boot in recovery mode. Live session would be the last resort. Easy task, unless he destroyed something else in the process.

Comment: I just tested this in virtual environment. He should be able to get to the login screen just fine. Then just (ctrl + alt + F1) to access terminal. And ctrl + alt + F7 to get back to graphical and login normally.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Still locked out.

Comment: I can boot to normal log in screen. It does seem to recognize my password. It just doesn't access my user folder /home/randy. When I go to terminal the first line says something like bash permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Just run in terminal

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> /home/randy
```

If your user name is randy then

```
sudo chown -R randy:randy /home/randy
```

Comment: In a Live System is no user randy, therefore the user can't be set.

Comment: @A.B. There is no need to boot from live. It can be done from recovery.

Comment: Yes, I know. =)

Comment: @A.B. Or even with normal boot to console. OP knows how to get there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Start the recovery mode.

1. Boot into the GRUB menu

   Press and hold the *left* <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during boot.
2. Start the recovery mode

   Select the entries *Advanced* and *recovery mode*
3. Open the root console

   Select the entry *root*
4. Remount the root partition

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```
5. Mount your home partition, if your `/home` is on a separate partition
6. Change the permissions

   ```
   chown -R <your_user_name>:<your_user_name> /home/<your_user_name>
   ```

Comment: Please see the edited question above. I still get the same results. Randy

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo chown -R randy /home/randy` in the console (Press CTRL+ALT+F1) should fix your problem.