# Restore login after modifying /etc/shadow permissions

Tags: permissions, login, etc

I locked my screen for a moment and now I am unable to login back into my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, not even in a "Guest Session". After a moment of panic, I realized that I am the responsible, as I think I executed the following (I'm 99% sure) a moment ago:

```
sudo chmod 555 /etc/shadow
```

Is there a way I can restore the original permissions of `/etc/shadow` (with an Ubuntu live CD maybe?). I'm also 99% sure no other files were modified in my moment of stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard permissions for the file `/etc/shadow` are `640 (-rw-r-----)`

```
% stat -c "%a %n" /etc/shadow
640 /etc/shadow

% ls -la /etc/shadow
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1870 Aug 25 17:32 /etc/shadow
```

---

Therefore boot your system in [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/636479/367165) (you need only the steps 1..4) and change the permission again:

```
chmod 640 /etc/shadow
```

In the recovery mode, you don't need `sudo`

---

If that does not work, because you have to enter a password and it does not work, follow Plan B:

- Boot a Live System
- Mount the root `/` partition, usually `/etc` is not located in its own partition
- Go into the roou account

  ```
  sudo su
  ```
- Change the permission

  ```
  chmod 640 /etc/shadow
  ```

Comment: When I open the root console, I am prompted `Give root password for maintenance` and I get stuck at that point.

Comment: Plan B, boot a Live System, mount the partition and change the permission.

Comment: I used plan B and it worked. It was worse than I thought, as I had modified the content of `/etc/shadow`, so what I did was re-generating it from `/etc/passwd` using `pwconv`. It didn't even work after that though, so I `passwd` to generate a new root and user passwords and everything is back to normal now.. hopefully :)